# Bad EXC_BAD_ACCESS when scrolling through UITableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I initiated a UITableView with the following code:

```
ProductTableView *tableProd = [[ProductTableView alloc]initWithNibName:@"ProductTableView" bundle:nil];
```

the xib file does exist!

Since I am displaying this table in a separate UIView I add it to this screen by:

```
[content addSubview:tableProd.view];
```

I used xcode to create a standard UITableView and set the following functions:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 10;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }
   cell.textLabel.text = @"test";    
   return cell;
}
```

The table is displayed in the simulator with 10 rows filled with test. However, when I start scrolling, and the first cell leaves the screen, the simulator crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I tried using Instruments to detect the NSZombie and the software flaged the zombie. Unfortunately I cant trace this error back to the cause.
[image: Instruments Screenshot of the Zombie]

Does anyone have a idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: Have you cheked, that the reuseidentifier is set and the same to the code in the xib too ?

Comment: pls paste ur didselect method of tableview.

Comment: Stacktrace says that "didSelectRowAtIndexPath:" was called in your code. Could you please show this delegate callback?

Answer (score 1):

if you're adding the view of a view controller as a subview of another view controllers view, i would guess that the ProductTableView view controller is being dealloced (since adding as a subview retains the view, but not the view controller it belongs to)

add the ProductTableView view controller as a property of the container view controller so that it is retained